# Does mysql need additional indexes for queries on subset of existing index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

If I have an index on 4 column:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   from varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   to varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   departure date NOT NULL,
   arrival date NOT NULL,
   ....
   KEY mykey(from, to, departure, arrival)
);
```

When I do a query for equalness on only `from` and `to`, would I have to create an additional index `KEY fromto (from, to)` so that mysql is using an index for the scan?

Or would mysql reuse the existing index, as I'm only querying a subset of it with `SELECT * from mytable where from = 'New' and to = 'York'`? Or even only a query on `...from = 'New'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) says;

> If the table has a multiple-column index, `any leftmost prefix of the index can be used` by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

you may use `explain` to see whether the index is used or not.

```
mysql> explain select * from mytable where `from` = 'a' and `to` = 'b';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | mykey         | mykey | 164     | const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Is the order interchangeable? Eg `col2, col1` would use the index too, right?

Comment: @membersound order is not important in that case, mysql optimizer make some calculations, optimizations to make it most efficient. I changed the order of where conditions, got the same `explain` response.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need an additional index. As long as the prefix part of an index can be used, the index can be used.

If you have an index on (from, to, departure, arrival), you can use this index for any query that has an equality match on:

(from)

(from, to)

(from, to, departure)

(from, to, departure, arrival)

in any order.